# How to make different SSIS packages sequential to avoid locking?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, locking, ssis-2008

I have two **different** SSIS packages (ABC,XYZ) running on a same server. I want the package XYZ to run only if package ABC is not running. Also I want XYZ to wait till ABC completes execution & start execution once ABC completes.

ABC runs after every 20 minutes (genrally finishes in 20 minutes but sometimes takes more than that ) and XYZ runs once a day.

I can do the above task using script task (GetRunningPackages()) in beginning on XYZ.

Is there any other way  of doing it . Please suggest as above issue causes locking.

Answer (score 1):

You could log the start and stop of ABC to a table, then XYZ could check the most recent row and not start if there is a start value but no corresponding stop value.

We have had good results with this, and it scales to support multiple package sets quite easily.

Comment: Thanks Eric , that sounds an interesting and feasible solution. But one concern of mine is as ABC runs after every 20 minutes so log entries will be bloating up the log file. Does my concern makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it is a significant factor.  A month's worth of processing will result in just over 2k log entries, which is trivial for a database to maintain.  If you want, set the XYZ package to delete all log entries older than 7 days when it runs every 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

you should look up interprocess communication.
Named semaphore would work in such scenario as it would allow only one to run at the time. There are more options in interprocess communication.